# ACPI Error:Cannot release Mutex [ECMX], not acquired (20210730/exmutex-357)

Tags: suspend, dell, acpi

Laptop is Dell. The battery was low. Then the screen went to automatically suspend mode. After logging in, the screen went black and showed this message.

```
[7177.571034]ACPI Error:Cannot release Mutex [ECMX], not acquired (20210730/exmutex-357) 
[7177.571052] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB. PC00.LPCB.ECDBV._Q66 due to previous error 
  (AE_AML_MUTEX_NOT_ACQUIRED) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

What to do? I cannot restart it.

```
To perform a hard reset on a Dell computer, follow these steps.
★ Turn off the computer.
★ Disconnect the power cable (for desktops), or disconnect the AC adapter and remove the battery (for Dell laptops with removable battery).
NOTE: For Dell laptops that have a nonremovable battery, learn How to Reset Real Time Clock (RTC) to Recover Your Dell Laptop.
For Dell laptops with removable batteries, see the user guide of your Dell laptop for step-by-step instructions to safely remove the battery.
NOTE: On select Dell Latitude laptops, learn How to Use Forced ePSA to Recover from POST or Boot Failure on Dell Latitude PCs.
Disconnect all devices such as USB drives, printers, webcams, and media cards (SD/xD).
★ Press and hold the power button for 15 to 20 seconds to drain the residual power.
★ Connect the power cable (for desktops) or AC adapter and battery (for laptops).
★ Turn on the computer.
```

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product or release detail, are we to guess?

Comment: After hard resetting the problem was gone.

Comment: So to recap you shut down the computer improperly and that caused a hardware issue and a hardware reset fixed it? Not a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: I have a very similar problem in ubuntu 22.10, I installed a new kernel 6.2.16 (and replaced 22.04), for trying to solve suspend problems, but it seems some times some problems still happens. Dell Inspiron 15 5510